# Fourier transform of algebraic function with arbitrary power

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Does anyone have any suggestions for performing the following Fourier transform:

$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,)^\Delta}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\cos(k x) \, dx$$

where $\Delta$ is real and negative. Unfortunately, I cannot find the expression in any table.

Comment: Is $\Delta$ real.?

Comment: Yes, $\Delta$ is a real variable. I'm interested in the regime in which $\Delta<0$.

Comment: i dont't think a closed form solution is available here...maybe you might try some asymptotic expansions?

Comment: are you sure that the numerator isn't $(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})^\Delta$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I found the Fourier transform for that function in a table so I was hoping that the same would be true for the integral above.